# Call Fancybox within .on() click function while maintaining the gallery feature

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to load content with dynamic width within Fancybox iframe. To achieve resizing of the iframe to fit the content, I need to pass the content width to Fancybox call. I have done this using the following:

```
jQuery('#container').on('click', '.fancybox-iframe', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var iframeWidth = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('id'));

    jQuery(this).fancybox({
        width           : iframeWidth,
        height          : '100%',
        autoSize        : true,
        fixed           : true,
        type            : 'iframe',
        loop            : false,
        padding         : 0,
        closeBtn        : false,
        afterLoad       : function() {
                            jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        },
        afterClose      : function() {
                            jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        },
        helpers         : {title: {type: 'outside'}, overlay: {opacity: 0.8, css: {'background-color': '#FFFFFF'}}, thumbs: {width: 50, height: 50}, buttons: {}}
    });
});
```

The HTML for the above:

```
<a id="<?php echo $content_width; ?>" class="fancybox-iframe fancybox.iframe" rel="gallery" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
<a id="<?php echo $content_width; ?>" class="fancybox-iframe fancybox.iframe" rel="gallery" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
<a id="<?php echo $content_width; ?>" class="fancybox-iframe fancybox.iframe" rel="gallery" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
```

The above code has two issues: First, I have to click the hyperlink twice, every time for Fancybox to appear. The second issue is that, this does not work with the `rel` attribute of the HREF and therefore does not display content as a Fancybox gallery. To overcome the gallery issue, I replaced `jQuery(this).fancybox({` with `jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').fancybox({`. This made the galleries feature work. However, Fancybox now only takes the value of `iframeWidth` variable for the first link clicked.

Any ideas on how to pass content width variable to Fancybox and also maintain the gallery feature? BTW, I am working with Fancybox 2.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using fancybox v2.x, you don't need to use jQuery `.on()` method since fancybox already uses "*live*" so

```
  $(".fancybox-iframe").bind('click', function(){
    var iframeWidth = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    }).fancybox({
   //options
    width : iframeWidth,
  });
```

should do the trick.

**UPDATE**:

I have revised my code above and actually things can be much simpler than expected.

The following code allows you to pass the `width` parameter dynamically through the `ID` **AND** have a gallery of iframes (with just a single click). Just add to the `afterLoad` callback this :

```
jQuery(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox({
 //other API options here
 afterLoad: function(){
  var iframeWidth = parseInt(jQuery(".fancybox-iframe").eq(this.index).attr('id'));
  this.width = iframeWidth
 }
});// fancybox
```

Notice that you don't need to set the option `width`.

**OPTION 2**

Alternatively you could also pass the `width` parameter dynamically using the `data-width` attribute (if you are using HTML5 `DOCTYPE`) instead of the `ID` (and use the `ID` for what it matters). I think that would be a more elegant solution.

Your html then should look like

```
<a data-width="<?php echo $content_width; ?>" id="myID" class="fancybox-iframe fancybox.iframe" rel="gallery" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
```

and the javascript is pretty much the same

```
jQuery(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox({
 //options
 afterLoad: function(){
  var iframeWidth = jQuery(".fancybox-iframe").eq(this.index).data("width");
  this.width = iframeWidth
 }
});// fancybox
```

I have set a DEMO with the two options that you can [see here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/passWidth_twoMethods_29Feb12.html)

Last note: Fancybox uses a `padding` of 15px so the total `width` will be `iframeWidth + 30`, unless you set the `padding` option to `0`.

Comment: This does not work. Clicking the link takes the browser to linked page instead of opening it in Fancybox. Tried with event.preventDefault(); as well.

Comment: It does work even without `.preventDefault()`. Check that you don't have any other js errors that mat break the code. I will make a demo in the meantime. Also I just notice that `width : iframeWidth` won't work,... you rather may need to pass the value with the `afterLoad` callback like `afterLoad:function(){this.width = iframeWidth}`. I will include that in the demo too. More soon.

Comment: You have nailed it. I have a working code using your 1st option.  I'll look into your suggestion for using HTML5 doctype and passing width via data. Thx a lot for the help.

Comment: btw, you can access width also using `this.width = $(this.element).data('width');`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for colorbox (another lightbox) and may give you a look into what you need to do:

```
...
onComplete: function () {
   var container = $('.cboxIframe').contents().find(".innerElementWithWidthAndHeight");
   $.fn.colorbox.myResize(container.width() + 20, container.height() + 20);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I do not see any methods specified on Fancybox website for resizing the width. I am not sure if this is available with Fancybox 2.0.5. It was available with earlier versions.